# how to extract text from html tags which contain other tags ? regular expression

Tags: php, python, html, regex

i have this html text:

```
<span id="target_text"> 
         sample text
         <span class="red"> word1 </span>
         <span class="green"> <b> word2 </b> word3 </span>
         <b> word4 </b>
         <span> word5 </span>
         <b> word6 </b>
         <a class="itlink" href="http:www.example.com" > Details </a>
</span>
```

I need to get the displayed text inside the span with id = `target_text`  :

```
sample text word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 Details
```

note: i don't how much b or span tags children there are inside the target_text.

i tried this expression:

```
preg_match_all ( "%target_text.*?>(.*?<.*?>.*?<.*?>.*?)</span>%s", $html_text, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER );
```

which first will locate the span target_text and then get every thing that between `><` or out side them. but it didn't work ?

Comment: You really can't use Regular Expressions to parse HTML...

Comment: An XML parser is normally a good alternative to a regex, in my experience

Comment: i wouldnt say you cant, more so, you SHOULDNT. use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), [`lxml'`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/2.3), [`HTMLParser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html), etc. these are just way better. trust me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use regex to parse HTML. Ever.

Learn what [xpaths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) are, and you will be much better off (xpaths can be used in many languages). Python has [eTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) built in which will do fine on your example, but [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is a much better libary (with a mostly-compatible interface).

```
In [1]: import lxml.html

In [2]: html = lxml.html.fromstring("""<span id="target_text">
   ...:          sample text
   ...:          <span class="red"> word1 </span>
   ...:          <span class="green"> <b> word2 </b> word3 </span>
   ...:          <b> word4 </b>
   ...:          <span> word5 </span>
   ...:          <b> word6 </b>
   ...:          <a class="itlink" href="http:www.example.com" > Details </a>
   ...: </span>""")

In [3]: html.xpath('//span[@id="target_text"]')[0].text_content()
Out[3]:' \n         sample text\n          word1 \n           word2  word3 \n          word4 \n          word5 \n          word6 \n          Details \n'
```

You'll want to clean up the result text a bit to get rid of the useless extra whitespace.

```
In [9]: content = html.xpath('//span[@id="target_text"]')[0].text_content()
In [10]: import re
In [11]: re.sub('\s+', ' ', content).strip()
Out[11]: 'sample text word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 Details'
```

Presto!

Comment: thank you for your answer. actually i have no experience with xpath queries. and your query doesn't return the "sample text"

Comment: @david I've updated it.